# Pandas: Efficiently perform numerous modifications to column names

Tags: python, pandas

How can you make numerous modifications to dataframe columns avoiding boilerplate code.

Reproducible example:

```
data = {'Subject Id': ['1', '2', '3'],
        'First-Name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen'], 
        'Last, name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman', 'Ali']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Subject Id', 'First-Name', 'Last, name'])
```

`df`

```
    Subject Id  First-Name  Last, name
0   1           Alex        Anderson
1   2           Amy         Ackerman
2   3           Allen       Ali
```

To clean the column names I'd usually do something like this:

```
df.columns = [l.lower() for l in df.columns]
df.columns = [s.replace('-', ' ') for s in df.columns]
df.columns = [d.replace(',', ' ') for d in df.columns]
```

But sometimes I need to make far more than 3 modifications. Is there a way to chain such operations together or otherwise do this more efficiently?

Comment: Apart from the answers posted over here, you can also leverage the use of `string.punctuation` to do this by itself which has around 32 chars in it's punctuation list, incase you've got more such operations to perform. You need to call `.str.translate` method however to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call vectorised [`.str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods and chain these calls on your columns, here we use [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html#pandas.Series.str.lower) and [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace):

```
In [91]:
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace('-|,', ' ')
df

Out[91]:
  subject id first name last  name
0          1       Alex   Anderson
1          2        Amy   Ackerman
2          3      Allen        Ali
```

Note also there was nothing stopping you from just combining everything in a single list comprehension:

```
In [93]:
df.columns = [l.lower().replace('-', ' ').replace(',',' ') for l in df.columns]
df

Out[93]:
  subject id first name last  name
0          1       Alex   Anderson
1          2        Amy   Ackerman
2          3      Allen        Ali
```

A list comprehension maybe quicker on such a small number of columns:

**timings**

```
In [96]:
%timeit [l.lower().replace('-', ' ').replace(',',' ') for l in df.columns]
%timeit df.columns.str.lower().str.replace('-|,', ' ')

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.26 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 284 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.columns = [l.lower().replace('-', ' ').replace(',', ' ') for l in df.columns]
```